# Paperclip custom path with id belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip inside a project.

The concerned model look like this :

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail                              # Track model with paper_trail
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>"}, 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/project_#{:project_id}/ressources/:basename_:style.:extension"

  belongs_to :project

end
```

As you see I want to have the id of concerned project in my image path, how can I make this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>"}, 
 path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:project_id/ressources/:basename_:style.:extension"
```

and then write

```
Paperclip.interpolates :project_id do |attachment, style|
    "project_#{attachment.instance.project_id}"
  end
```